# Wrong e-mail addresses in Outlook are hard to detect

Tags: microsoft-outlook

One of the most annoying features of standalone outlook is the fact that it is hiding the real e-mail addresses in messages.

So it will show

```
To:Joe Internet
```

instead of

```
To:Joe Internet <joe@internet.com>
```

This coupled with autocomplete and replying to all can lead to lost e-mails with very little possibility to trace them.

For example, if during certain mail exchange, I replied to Joe Internet  it is very hard later to examine exchange from the one side and determine what the problem was because the quoted To will contain only Joe Internet and will not show an error in the e-mail address (missing m).

So, are there any strategies to avoid the above design problem, in particular

- is there a way to force outlook validate messages against addressbook (without Exchange server, with LDAP directory and/or with outlook addressbook)
- is there a way to force outlook to show both display name and the raw e-mail address so that it will subsequently be coded

Of course, any other suggestions that would make the issue go away are very welcome.